# Sakai + Preference Tool + make Visible

Tags: sakai

I want to change the language of sakai . so I need the preference tool. How do I make visible to administrator?

Thanks,
Nirav

Answer (score 3):

Using the Admin Workspace Sites tool you can add the User Preferences tool to the ~admin site and then the admin user can manage their own language. Other users can do the same via their My Workspace site.

Note that if you want to change the language of the entire Sakai installation, you need to set it in JAVA_OPTS.

Answer (score 1):

To change the default language of Sakai specify it as a command line option when starting tomcat. For example to change the default language to french add:

```
-Duser.language=fr
```

to the startup options. More details can be found on the [Sakai i18n FAQ](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=31162384). Currently it isn't possible to change the default language for all users of Sakai using the web interface.

Comment: Not from command line . I want it to be done by administrator using GUI only.Is there any possible way using preference tool or some other way?